# Reference request - infinite ramification theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I want to study the ramification theory for an infinite Galois extension. Regarding infinite Galois theory, I can find some references, but I cannot find anything that satisfies me about the ramification theory.

I would like to have also a systematic approach to the subject. I find only the definition of an unramified extension, but what does it mean that a prime is totally ramified in an infinite Galois extension? What are the basic strategies to prove that a prime is totally ramified using its inertia group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic treatment of infinite Galois theory is not likely to include a discussion of ramification because the latter is a more specialized topic, belonging to algebraic number theory, or, if you like, algebraic geometry. The second appendix to Washington's book on cyclotomic fields gives a very basic introduction to ramification of primes in infinite (Galois) extensions of number fields, and I would say this is a reasonable starting point if you have never seen this material.

In answer to your specific question about totally ramified primes, if $L/K$ is an arbitrary (i.e. not necessarily finite) Galois extension of a number field $K$, then a nonarchimedean/finite prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ is *totally ramified* in $L$ if for one (equivalently any) prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L$ lying above $\mathfrak{p}$, the inertia subgroup $I(\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p})$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is equal to $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.

The natural context for a more refined study of ramification of this kind is *local*, meaning the setting of extensions of nonarchimedean local fields (e.g. $\mathbf{Q}_p$). Indeed, ramification in the global context is already studied one (based) prime at a time, and once one fixes such a prime, one can complete with respect to the prime in order to move to a local context which in which all the desired ramification information is available. The local context is the one in which a clean treatment of *higher ramification groups* may be carried out. There are many books covering ramification in extensions of complete (maybe even just Henselian) discretely valued fields, for example Serre's classic *Local Fields*. Defining higher ramification groups for infinite extensions of such fields requires some contortions with the so-called upper and lower numbering (explained in Serre's book), but it is extremely important, for example, in defining the conductor of a $p$-adic Galois representation, in understanding $p$-adic Lie extensions and the related notion of an arithmetically profinite (APF) extension, and, generally, in $p$-adic Hodge theory.

I do not know any strategies for proving that a prime is totally ramified using its inertia group beyond just making use of the definition, which is, as I said above, that the inertia group is equal to the entire Galois group.

Edit: Regarding my last comment, I guess it is worth mentioning that the a prime is totally ramified in an infinite extension if and only if it is totally ramified in every finite subextension.

Comment: Good answer, as complete as one might ask for in this context. Plus 1.

Comment: Keenan, I have a doubt on a subject that maybe is familiar for you. I would appreciate if you could look at that, giving a proof of just some sketchy ideas https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833612/a-unit-of-an-extension-of-a-totally-real-field-herbrands-theorem

Answer (score 1):

May I also suggest Moreno, Advanced Analytic Number Theory, Part I: Ramification Theoretic Methods (Contemporary Mathematics, Volume 15).